# How I can delete extra whitespaces between characters in string python

Tags: python, string, normalization

How I can normalize a string that contains extras whitespaces between
characters

From this

```
 'I  n e e d  t o  d e l e t e  t h e  e x t r a  w h i t e s p a c e  b e t w e e n  c h a r a c t e r s'
```

In to

```
'I need to delete the extra whitespace between characters'
```

Comment: Is the following rephrasing correctly interpreting your question? "I want to delete every whitespace that is followed by a non-whitespace character"

Comment: I don't think that's quite right, @lucidbrot: between words, there are two spaces in the original.

Comment: @hBy2Py in which case the first whitespace would be retained and the second deleted, right?

Comment: yes, is correctly

Comment: @lucidbrot Ah, yep, you're right. I was thinking of it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option using `split` and `join`:

```
>>> s = 'I  n e e d  t o  d e l e t e  t h e  e x t r a  w h i t e s p a c e  b e t w e e n  c h a r a c t e r s'
>>> ''.join(c if c else " " for c in s.split(" "))
'I need to delete the extra whitespace between characters'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex, delete spaces not followed by spaces:

```
s = 'I  n e e d  t o  d e l e t e  t h e  e x t r a  w h i t e s p a c e  b e t w e e n  c h a r a c t e r s'

import re
out = re.sub('\s(?!\s)', '', s)
```

output: `'I need to delete the extra whitespace between characters'`

Alternative to handle any number of spaces, if more than one, only keep one, else delete:

```
s = 'I  n e e d  t o     d e l e t e  t h e  e x t r a  w h i t e s p a c e  b e t w e e n  c h a r a c t e r s'

import re
out = re.sub('\s+?(\s)?', r'\1', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, you want to remove every space that is not followed by a non-whitespace character. Doing exactly this in the python shell:

```py
>>> import re
>>> s =  'I  n e e d  t o  d e l e t e  t h e  e x t r a  w h i t e s p a c e  b e t w e e n  c h a r a c t e r s'
>>> re.sub(r"\s(\S)", r"\1", s)
'I need to delete the extra whitespace between characters'
>>>
```

The `r"\s(\S)"` says "match a whitespace and then a non-whitespace. The non-whitespace is in group `1`. The `r"\1"` says to replace this full match with the group `1`.